# Git / VSCode Bug or cloud bug

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, icloud

It seems to me that Git is laughing at me !
Sometimes, i have not realized when exactly, but Git auto stage/changes my files...
Yesterday, i staged all my files, commit and push, so everything was clean.
This morning, i opened VSCode an i saw a looooot of changes!

[image]

[image]

As you can see, it's a bit messy!!!
Do you know how i can fix it???
for info, I'm the only one to work on this repo on github.
I have the impression that it's maybe coming from icloud...is it possible?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: To further investigate that, you should navigate to that directory in shell (cmd or Powershell) and run `git status`, `git log -10`, those commands would give you idea what is going on.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i made it, but it's the same as the picture, it lists all the "untracked files" and ll the "changes to be committed". nothing special, it reacts as if i was responsible of this changes, but when i quit VSC yesterday, everything was committed and clean....

Comment: if you clone the github repo again and compare the two directories what is the difference? If you see the same result with the command line git commands it is **not** a VSC problem, VSC just shows the result git produces.

Comment: this is very strange, i had this problem several times this morning but it's not doing it any more.... thank you for your help anyway :) very kind of you!